# Haskell function definition

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble defining a function in Haskell. What I want to do is input a variable of type `EnvV` and one of type `Store` and return a `State` type variable:

```
type Variable = String
type Z = Integer
type T = Bool
type State = Variable -> Z
type Location = Z
type Store = Location -> Z
type EnvV = Variable -> Location

search :: EnvV -> Store -> State
search envV store = envV(store)
```

Comment: A function of type `EnvV` takes `Variable` a.k.a. `String`, while you're applying it to `Store`. Please elaborate what you want to do.

Comment: Unrelated note: Parentheses are not needed for function application (so you should write `envV store` instead of `envV(store)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try matching the types:

You have `EnvV` which is `Variable -> Location`
and `Store` which is `Location -> Z`

And you want the output of `State` which is `Variable -> Z`

Can you see the connection between them ? You have to eliminate `Location` between them.

```
search :: EnvV -> Store -> State
search envV store = \x -> store (envV x)
```

Since you want `Variable` in the output, introduce `x`  which denotes that. Then apply it to `envV` which will give you `Location` . Now apply that to `store` which will give `Z`. This will give you a type of `Variable -> Z` which is expected by you.

This can be written more concisely:

```
search :: EnvV -> Store -> State
search envV store = store . envV
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to simplify to:

```
type State = String -> Integer
type Store = Integer -> Integer

search :: State -> Store -> State
```

There are an infinite number of ways to implement this, but I'm going to guess that the result you want is simply the composition of the two functions.

```
search state store = store . state
```

Or more simply

```
search = flip (.)
```

Answer (score 0):

The type

```
search :: EnvV -> Store -> State
```

means

```
search :: EnvV -> Store -> Variable -> Z
```

Hence, you can use

```
search envV store var = store (envV var)
```

because `envV var` is a `Location`, which is then applied to `store` to produce a `Z`.

Note that the following code is correct, even if it's a bit puzzling

```
search :: EnvV -> Store -> State
search envV store var = store (envV var)
```

It's puzzling because its type shows two arguments, when the code below takes three. Equivalently, the code above is more commonly written as

```
search :: EnvV -> Store -> State
search envV store = \var -> store (envV var)
```

so that even in the definition we can find two arguments, and a result value which is actually a function of type `State` which maps every variable `var` into its value.

The code above can then further be simplified to use the function composition operator `.`, as @ChrisMartin already showed.